# application which was running fine on ios-9.3 but when i run it on anydevice with IOS-10 onwards it crashes at random points

Tags: objective-c, ios10

I have an application which was running fine on ios-9.3 but when i run it on anydevice with IOS-10 onwards it crashes at random points (crashes at different points every time) 
I am working in objective-C with Xcode-8
Here is my error log - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name '3pB-ff-s9x-view-jo5-RS-cHl' and directory 'Main.storyboardc''

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'QuestionTableViewCell''

I tried a few things 
- Checked the buildphase bundles resources (all xib file are present there) 
- removed all the xib refernces and add them back to project

Its very frustarting please help me

Answer (score 1):

I can not able to comment because of low rep. so writing here as an answer,
for exact solution you can search it in your storyboard by finding this "**3pB-ff-s9x-view-jo5-RS-cHl**", it will navigate you on exact on that control on storyboard which gives problem.

I hope it will helps you,

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for reply .This name changes everytime as u can see in next error that i post after this it changesn to 'QuestionTableViewCell'. so its coming at random points